# Local hexo not found

Tags: node.js, npm, hexo

I try to install Hexo on my server following the instructions:

```
[root@VM_150_20_centos ~]# yum install -y nodejs
[root@VM_150_20_centos ~]# npm install -g hexo-cli
[root@VM_150_20_centos ~]# hexo init blog
[root@VM_150_20_centos ~]# cd blog
[root@VM_150_20_centos blog]# npm install
[root@VM_150_20_centos blog]# hexo generate
```

when I try to generate, there is an error:

```
[root@VM_150_20_centos blog]# hexo generate

/root/blog/node_modules/hexo/lib/extend/tag.js:184
  body((err, result) => {
                      ^
ERROR Local hexo not found in ~/blog
ERROR Try running: 'npm install hexo --save'
```

I tried run `npm install hexo --save`, but it didn't help.

My server is CentOS6.8 64bit

Answer (score 0):

CentOS6 have old Node version.

Input `node -v` to see what version installed (~v0.10.x).

Old Node version [was dropped](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/commit/501eef5c993ccedf8674d869314fdc340e7eac15#diff-354f30a63fb0907d4ad57269548329e3) from maintain.

And look at [requirements under linux](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/blob/master/.travis.yml#L10-L12) for now:

```
node_js:
  - "6"
  - "node
```

It's mean at least [node version 6](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-and-npm-on-centos/) needed.

Answer (score -1):

try following code:

```
npm install -g hexo-cli
```

Comment: The issue won't be resolved by globally installing the `hexo-cli`.